# Update Intellisense _references.js file for certain folders

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, intellisense, references.js

We have a lot of legacy javascript code which spans about 300 different files in our project in `Scripts` folder. When I update `_references.js` file, all 300 files gets referenced and it bloats the Intellisense. We are moving on to new javascript code under `Scripts/New` folder but also keeping the old files. We are willing to sacrifice Intellisense for old files. And we want to update `_references.js` when new files are added or deleted under the `Scripts/New` folder. Is there a way to update `_references.js` only for the new folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
files.exclude": {
    "Scripts/New": true,
}
```

I found this config [github issue](https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-intellisense/issues/49).

add or append this entry in VScode config.
Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable and disable the auto sync feature via editor’s **context menu** button “Auto-sync JavaScript References” **in this js file**. You can always manually update the project’s JavaScript references using the context menu button “**Update JavaScript References**”.[check here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/10/10/_references-js-files-auto-sync-feature/)